# Define Regular Expression to match ending of URL

Tags: regex

What would the regular expression look like to include/exclude a specific URL? I posted two URLs below -I need a regex that will distinguish between the two.  The only difference in the two URLs is the ending: `type` vs `hcat`.

```
https://post.craigslist.org/k/WDEDan6W4xGILKcEW036_A/w7TH4?s=type                    
https://post.craigslist.org/k/WDEDan6W4xGILKcEW036_A/w7TH4?s=hcat
```

Comment: What you need is just an ordinary URL parser. Regex isn't the end-all be-all tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understood your question right.

But if you want to give the exact given URLs in - this should do:

```
"https://post\.craigslist\.org/k/WDEDan6W4xGILKcEW036_A/w7TH4\?s=(type|hcat)"
```

With this, Capture Group 1 would contain either type or hcat or nothing.

If you want to check based on this domain URL and the URL should end on the parameter s with type or cat, use this:

```
"https://post\.craigslist\.org/.*?s=(type|hcat)"
```

Note: The ? now marks the * as not greedy, it is not the escaped \? from above.